# VBA HTML - Retrieve input box value

Tags: html, vba, inputbox

I'm trying to get the value of an input box on an IE page, using VBA.

The solutions I've found didn't work. The HTML code is below.
I need to get the value of the bolded input box.

I used something like this:

1. IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).getelementsbytagname("tr")(3).getelementsbytagname("td")(1)

   I checked the values stored by the object in Excel Watch window and noticed that the **IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).getelementsbytagname("tr")(3)** returned a "TR" tag from the top of the page, contained by a different class, and not the one from "body"
2. IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).children(3).children(1).children(0) didn't take me anywhere either.

I searched a lot of related topics and I know it must be very simple to solve, but I'm stuck. Could you please help?

Thank you!

```
<div class="body">
    <table style="....
        <tbody>
           +<tr>
           +<tr>
           +<tr>
           -<tr>
               +<td class="cellpad"... >
               -<td class="cellpad"... >
                   **<input name="txtassignedcode" tabindex=....**
                    <script language=...
                    <script ... </script>
                <td class="cellpad"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim els, el

Set els = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each el in els
    If el.Name = "txtassignedcode" Then
         'do something with el
    End If
Next el
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I will try it out as soon as I fix another issue that I caused when trying to get the "txtassignedcode". I wanted to see what does IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")(0).children(3) reffer to and I assigned to it in VBA the value "test" . After that the Internet Explorer page didn't work any more and there is no HTML in it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't work :( the link works in firefox but not in explorer. I restarted the computer and nothing. I upgraded IE and nothing

Comment: You can't have "broken" the page via whatever you did with your VBA, so clearly something else is going on.

Comment: Yes, but what? and what else can I try? the page doesn't load, the end of the URL changed to "error" and the HTML disappeared.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the page you're trying to access, it's difficult to make any suggestions.  Start by trying the same page in IE but from a different PC.

Comment: I restarted the computer several times. The only page that isn't working is the one I've changed. I thought that if I upgrade IE it will fix the issue, but no.

Comment: It's a company intranet. The page loads on firefox and on other computers there is no issue with it

Comment: Sounds like an issue for your internal Helpdesk.

Comment: I fixed IE and tried the solution. It skips the loop. I think it's because the "input" tag in which the element is in doesn't close with "</input>", but with ";" . The closest tag to the element is that of the "body" class.

Comment: Hard to comment, since you didn't post the full HTML. `<input>` doesn't need a closing tag.